# SQLException : Timeout Expired.

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sqlexception

I have added the following code to establish connection between SQL Database and Xamarin.Android application. **It is working with Xamarin Console application and it is not working with Android application**.

```
static IDbConnection dbconn;
string conStr = "Data Source=dsname;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxxxx";
using (dbconn = new SqlConnection(conStr)) {
    dbconn.Open ();
}
```

While trying this with Android application I'm getting the following error

[image: SQLException]

Please guide me what i have missed here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin

Comment: I want to use sql database