# How do I create an SQLite database and connect with Xamarin using C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to create a demo Android app via Xamarin using C# in Visual studio.

I have set up the Xamarin environment on my system, but I am a very  beginner in Xamarin app development and SQLite databases. I have no idea how to create an SQLite database and how to connect in my Xamarin app using C#. I have planned to create a register-a-user functionality. Please suggest me any blog or article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin) or you can use [this](http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net) one.