# Accessing data from database in Xamarin Android using SQLite

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm writing an app and I'm trying to get data out of an existing database. I succeeded in importing the database and addressing it correctly [using this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin). When I try to execute a query, my object are empty.

This is my code

```
public void TestDB() {
        using (var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var cmd = new SQLite.SQLiteCommand (conn);
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from totem";
            var r = cmd.ExecuteQuery<Totem> ();

            tekst.Text = r[0].Title;
        }
    }
}

public class Totem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public string TotemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

According to debug, r is a list and it contains 395 entries (the number of entries there are in Totem), but the Totem objects are empty as you can see:

[image: debug]

Does anyone know how to initialize them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do the column names in your db map correctly to the names used in the Totem class?

Comment: Why don't you use the table directly? 'conn.Table<Totem>()' gives you access to the items in the table. How did you inject the items into the database? Did you use conn.CreateTable<Totem>() to create the table?

Comment: @Jason That was it, thanks!