# How to reference SQLite database that already exists in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I have created SQLite database and have copied it in the root of the project like that:

[image]

The database is called MobileSell.db It appears in Visual Studio like that:

[image]

My question is how can I reference it so afterwards I can say connection.InsertIntoTableArticles(value)(this is pseudo code)

Comment: [Please refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin)

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can refer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin)

There only three steps to achieve it:

1) Create `Assets` folder which is parallel with `Resources` folder in your project, put your `.db` file into it.

2) Copy the .db file to SDCard when first open the app;

3) Use `SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path)` to open your .db and query it.

Comment: Could you give more details on point  2) Copy the .db file to SDCard when first open the app?

Comment: Please use [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) to read from your `.db` file and use [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) to write to you sdcard. In Android, you can't open .db from `Assets` or `raw`  directly, so you need copy it to other folder, and  this `SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path)` can open any folder.

Comment: Instead of copying .db to SDCard, could I copy the .db file into the apk folder of the app and then reference it from there like that: SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path-to-apk-folder)?

Comment: Yes, like `/data/data/package name/test.db`