# Xamarin Forms with pre-loaded data in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I create my first mobile app in Xamarin Forms. As I'm a C#.NET developer, I was thinking straight forward methods to manage with databases.

I have a pre-loaded database "MyStoryTitles.db3", and I just want to show the contents.

My thinking was to:

- store the db3 file in a folder named Data
- connect to the file
- use list view to show the content

But when I researched, I came to know that we cannot do the SQLite in straight forward methods. What I understood from the online articles that I have to:

- store the db3 file as Asset ( for Android)
- copy the file prior opening it ( as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin))
- connect to the local copied db
- use list view to show the content

Is this the standard procedure ? Or can I store the db3 file as EmbeddedResource and do the database operation as normal ?

Comment: Where do you put the EmbeddedResource db3 file? In Xamarin.Forms or just in Xamarin .Android?

Comment: yes, that's the standard process.  SQLite cannot open a DB that is stored as an embedded resource or asset, that is why you need to copy it to a folder first

Comment: @Jason So is there any way to do direct connection ?

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT Right now, I put in a new folder named Data, with build Action EmbeddedResource

Comment: if you want to write to the database, you must do it this way.  If your db is read-only you can try including it as a file in your platform project and opening the SQLiteConnection directly from there