# Xamarin Forms - How do i use a Premade Local Database? [Solved]

Tags: database, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**EDIT : I will leave this here with the full instructions to my solution to add a premade database to xamarin forms in case any one ever needs it.**

So I have a **Database (.db3 / .db File)** and I use "DB Browser for SQLite" (https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to create and view my database.

**IMPORTANT : The class name in the next part must be EXACTLY the same as the table name. So if the table is named "Items" your class must also be named "Items"

---

**Targeting IOS / Android / UWP**

So here are my steps as to what I'm doing, maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

- Open visual studios > Xamarin Forms > **Blank App**
- Install **NuGet** package **sqlite-net-pcl** to my project
- Create a **class** to handle my Items like so

> ```
> public class Item
> {
>
>     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public int Name { get; set; }
>     public int Category { get; set; }
> }
> ```

- Add a ListView to my **MainPage.xaml** like so, called *itemListView*

> ```
>         <Grid>
>             <ListView x:Name="itemListView">
>                 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>                     <DataTemplate>
>                         <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"
>                                   Detail="{Binding Category}"/>
>                     </DataTemplate>
>                 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>             </ListView>
>         </Grid>
> ```

- I change **MainPage.xaml.cs** to the following code

> ```
>     public MainPage()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     protected override void OnAppearing()
>     {
>         base.OnAppearing();
>
>         using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabasePath))
>         {
>             conn.CreateTable<Item>();
>             var items = conn.Table<Item>().ToList();
>
>             itemListView.ItemsSource = items;
>         }
>     }
> ```

- Next, I change my **App.xaml.cs** , adding a **DatabasePath string** and changing the App constructor method to the following

> ```
>     public static string DatabasePath = string.Empty;
>
>     public App(string databasePath)
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>
>         DatabasePath = databasePath;
>
>         MainPage = new MainPage();
>     }
> ```

so what I'm trying to do here is access the database from the database path, leaving the databasePath open since **Android, IOS and UWP are all different**, according to what I've been reading. Later I add the database name as I will show below the steps.

---

At this point, I tweak the codes in each to the following :

**Android**

*MainActivity.cs*

> ```
>     private string dbName;
>     private string folderPath;
>     private string dbPath;
>
>     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>     {
>           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         dbName = "MyDatabase.db3";
>         folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
>         dbPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
>
>         CopyDatabase();
>
>         Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
>         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
>
>         LoadApplication(new App(dbPath));
>     }
>
>     protected void CopyDatabase()
>     {
>         // Check if your DB has already been extracted.
>         if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
>         {
>
>             using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(dbName)))
>             {
>                 using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
>                 {
>                     byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
>                     int len = 0;
>                     while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
>                     {
>                         bw.Write(buffer, 0, len);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Adding my .db3 database to **"Assets"** Folder in the **Android build**

---

**IOS**

*AppDelegate.cs*

> ```
>   public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
>     {
>
>         string dbName = "MyDatabase.db3";
>         string folderPath =                                                                                                              
>         Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"..", "Library");
>         string dbPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
>
>         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
>         LoadApplication(new App(dbPath));
>
>         return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
>     }
> ```

Adding my .db3 database to **"Resources"** Folder in the **IOS build**

---

**UWP**

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

> ```
>  public MainPage()
>     {
>         this.InitializeComponent();
>
>         string dbName = "MyDatabase.db3";
>         string folderPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
>         string dbPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
>         LoadApplication(new XamarinWhitey.App(dbPath));
>     }
> ```

Adding my .db3 database to **"Assets"** Folder in the **UWP build**

---

I expected this to work, though to my surprise It isn't working.

When I run the app (on any device) I've been trying different methods for over a week now and I Need some guidance and help to figure this out.

**Thanks all !**

Comment: you have to copy the database file from your app bundle to the destination path before you can open it

Comment: Hi, Could you elaborate a bit more? 

I'm still relatively new to Xamarin and all my programming experience is from Game Development. I'm still adjusting :) 

I've manually copied the database to each Platform's folder as I explained above (so I've copied it to 3 locations). Perhaps this is not what you mean. 

Best regards and thanks !

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715613/use-a-local-database-in-xamarin by adding the copy database, though It still Isn't working :/

Comment: You need to be more specific than that - "isn't working" doesn't tell me anything useful

Comment: Hi again, I figured it out and fixed my question for anyone else who comes across this :) Thank you @Jason for the help :)